# C# Class Diagram Dynamic Updating

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, uml

I have a class diagram in C# and to test it out I'd like to use it to generate code and then go back and edit it.  So I need to be able to go back and forth, generate code, update class diagram, rinse repeat.

However, for some reason I was only able to generate code once.  If I try to generate code again it says "another project might exist in the same solution".  How can I get around this?

Also when I update the generated code I'd like it to update the class diagram.  Is that possible?

Thank you.

Comment: I tried again on a different computer with Visual Studio 2010 (forgot to mention that I was using VS 2012) and the updates go both ways.  I'd still like to know why though, considering the 2010 is a trial version.

Comment: I tried to repro it, but it's working nicely in Visual Studio 2012 for me. I don't have to do anything to update. I add classes to a diagram that I create elsewhere or add them from the diagram and move them where I wanted. Anytime I save a change on the diagram or the class file it auto updates for me. Can you give better steps on how you got this to happen?

Comment: The difference a .cd vs a .classdiagram.  For some reason the .classdiagram does not update dynamically.  The .cd or "logical class designer" works.

Comment: It sounds like at this point you can now answer your own question. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is a .cd vs a .classdiagram. The .classdiagram does not update dynamically. The .cd or "logical class designer" does.